# Full page livewire components versus laravel controllers when doing resourceful CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I created a resourceful Laravel livewire component instead of going the controller route and was wondering if this practice is a clean approach? I've also eliminated the render method and have 3 methods that display a view. the problem with this I've noticed is that the `wire:submit.prevent` won't work.

for example routes

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductComponent');
```

Component:

```
class ProductComponent extends Component
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('mypage');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('create page');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(Model $model)
    {
        return view('edit page');
    }

    public function update()
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy(Model $model)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: `wire:submit.prevent wont work.` Any errors?

Comment: no errors, the page posts as in refreshes

Comment: I've never been able to get a full page Livewire component to work when called from the router, for whatever reason it loses it's Livewire functionality. I would just make a shell view for the router to load and then include the livewire component with @ livewire in that view.